# UVs resetting to same random pattern when I close the file

Tags: uv

When I edit my UVs (I'm attempting to map for textures), save, close the program and then re-open the file, all of my Uvs have reset back to the same strange pattern every time and does not keep whatever changes I make, essentially stopping me from mapping the model and I do not understand why.

I have tried resetting the Uv map, and I have tried deleting the Uv map and I have tried appending the model over into a new file and nothing works. It is like the model has somehow saved this specific Uv map?

I have two models (both characters edited from the same base model I made on separate occasions) this has happened to and I do not know why.

[image: Before Saving - I have uv mapped the eye and moved it to a clear area][image: After I re-open - the area I just edited has moved back its original location]

EXTRA INFO - It seems that exporting the object without Uv's fixes this problem on this model, but does not explain why this was happening. This therefore does not tell me how to fix this on my other model which is having the same problem. I would do the same thing but I have already rigged and textured the model and would very much like to fix the problem itself without deleting the existing UV map and therefore losing several hours of work. Or if the problem were to happen again further down the line (as it did on the other model)  I would not want to have to delete the entire UV map to start fresh each time the problem occurs.

Comment: That should not happen. Everything usually stay still once saved. Looks like the object in the second picture has more faces than the one above. Why? Could you post a picture showing the whole Uv map? Has the object multiple uv's? Is there any modifier? Consider the option to upload the problematic object for a deeper inspection.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration, I have updated the pictures to better show what happens overall, and added some notes at the bottom on a partial fix.
I would very much appreciate any help you could give as I have been struggling with this for quite some time.

Comment: If you separate the eye faces in a different file, does you experience the same behaviour? Would it be possible to upload that if you don't want to share the whole file? As you understood it's not the default behaviour and I never experienced it: giving a look at the overall settings would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not really sure if there is a better way to upload this but here is the object I am experiancing doffuiculty with in dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwtk0xjqr0me8as/Maric_Broken.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Keyframed UVs

As most of all the properties, UV island coordinates can be individually keyframed.

By examining the **Outliner** and the **Graph editor** you can realize that each island has fixed location coordinates for the current animation.

[image]

If you modify the UV island position and save without overriding the keframes values, the island would come back to the stored position.

If those keframes are needed, you must **Insert** a new keframe upon the old one before saving.

Comment: I can see what I have done wrong now, thank you so much for your help! This seems to have fixed the problem and I now understand why this has happened and how to avoid this in the future.

Comment: Glad it helped! Still I'm not sure how you managed to keyframe them: I saw no obiouvs shortcut for doing that. Were Maybe  you using a particular add-on?